# Children's book with a boy, who has a putty-like translation device, and a dinosaur-like alien

Tags: story-identification, childrens-novel

I'm looking for a children's sci-fi book I read as a kid, 20ish years ago. I vaguely remember it having a kid and a reptilian or dinosaur looking alien. The most vivid thing I remember is that translator device was like a little piece of putty or something similar that the kid had to put behind or in his ear (for some reason I remember it being behind his ear).

I remember this book every once and a while and go searching for it but can never find it. I literally don't remember anything else other than the translator device and no idea why that has stuck with me.

I *thought* it might be this book:
[Children's sci-fi book with an alien named Yacob looking for a kid with technology](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/74159/childrens-sci-fi-book-with-an-alien-named-yacob-looking-for-a-kid-with-technolo)

However searching that book on internet archive I can't find anything in that book regarding a translator device. I could be wrong, and it could be in the later books in the trilogy that I don't see on the website and if that's the case just let me know. I know this is vague and not very specific but any help would be wildly appreciated.